# How do I capture parts of a string in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

In php I can write

```
preg_match('/a(.*)b(.*)c/', '00a123b456c00', $result);
```

and in $result I will get `123` in `$result[1]`, `456` in `$result[2]` and `a123b456c` in `$result[0]`. How do I capture text matched with regex and it's different parts like that in Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
(let ((str "00a123b456c00"))
  (when (string-match "a\\(.*\\)b\\(.*\\)c" str)
    (list (match-string 0 str)
          (match-string 1 str)
          (match-string 2 str))))
```